# Why we use struts.custom.i18n.resources?

Tags: jakarta-ee, struts2

Why we `struts.custom.i18n.resources` in Struts2 Framework? what are its benefits and what happens if we don't define it?

Comment: It is used for loading custom default resource bundles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is used to declare the global recourse bundles of your application.

Struts 2 searches in the following order for a resources:

1. ActionClass.properties
2. Interface.properties (every interface and sub-interface)
3. BaseClass.properties (all the way to Object.properties)
4. ModelDriven's model (if implements ModelDriven), for the model
   object repeat from 1
5. package.properties (of the directory where class is located and
   every parent directory all the way to the root directory)
6. search up the i18n message key hierarchy itself
7. global resource properties

The constant you ask about is to declare the bundles searched in 7.

Reference: http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/localization.html

Benefits --> Declare cross functional globally available properties.

What if you don't define it --> Nothing bad is going to happen.